# Reversing the Reversed Word - Assembly

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I am having trouble with a homework in assembly. The goal of this program is to reverse each letter  so `CIS 335/535 is a great course` to `esruoc taerg a si 535/533 SIC` which my program does but then it is also supposed to convert that to `course great a is 335/535 CIS` which my program does not hence why I have the final output commented. My code spews out something like `cis 335/535 si a great course` in that last block.

```
    TITLE MASM Assignment 3 reverse a string word by word                   (main.asm)

; Description: Reverse a string character by character in-place then reverse word for word using nested loops
; 
; Revision date:

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
source    BYTE   "CIS 335/535 is a great course",0
ecxbkp DWORD  ?     ;save ecx if necessary 


.code
main PROC

mov  edx,OFFSET source
    call WriteString
    call Crlf                       ; print\r\n


mov ecx, LENGTHOF source                ;initialize loop counter                                               
mov esi, OFFSET source                  ;esi starting address of string           
mov edi, OFFSET source                                                
dec edi                           

END_STRING:
inc edi
mov al,[edi]
cmp al,0                             ;find zero byte
jnz END_STRING                       ;jump back to END_STRING if al is not 0

dec edi                              ;edi points to end of string
shr ecx, 1                           ;ecx is  loop count (shift one = length/2)


L1: 
 mov bl, [esi]                      ;load characters
 mov al, [edi]
 mov [esi], al                      ;swap characters
 mov [edi], bl
 inc esi                            ;update forward pointer by 1
 dec edi                            ;decrement backward pointer by 1


 loop L1                            ;and loop

 ; display the string

    mov  edx,OFFSET source
    call WriteString
    call Crlf                    ; print\r\n


;Use nested loops to reverse word for word

mov ecx, LENGTHOF source              ;set outer loop count ecx= entire length
mov esi, OFFSET source                ;esi points to start of string
mov edi, OFFSET source
dec edi

mov ecxbkp, ecx                     ;save outer loop count

L2:                                 ; go through beginning to end of string copy space character for length

inc edi
mov al, [edi]                       ;move edi address into al register
cmp al, ' '                         ;find space character 
loop L2

mov ecx, 16                         ;modify inner loop count (length/2) (for swap) 
dec edi

L3:                                 ; reverse/swap word for word
 mov bl,[esi]               
 mov al,[edi]                       ;load words
 mov [esi], al
 mov [edi],bl                       ;swap words
 inc esi                            ;update forward pointer by 1
 dec edi                            ;decrement backward pointer by 1

 loop L3                            ;and loop

 mov ecxbkp, ecx                    ;restore outer loop count

 ; display the string

    ;mov     edx,OFFSET source
    ;call WriteString
    ;call Crlf                       ; print\r\n

exit
main ENDP

END main

    enter code here
```

Comment: The lazy way: Loop through the string and push each character onto the stack, go back to the start of the string and populate it by popping the same number of letters off the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some changes to get you on the way:

Change `loop L2` into `jne L2`
Don't use a fixed value of 16 in ECX but calculate the exact length of the word.
Save the position in EDI in a variable to be able to continu with the next word after you will have reversed this one in your L3 loop.

```
L2:
inc edi
mov al, [edi]     ;move edi address into al register
cmp al, ' '       ;find space character 
jne L2
mov SavedPointer, edi
lea ecx,[edi-1]
sub ecx,esi       ;ECX is length of current word
```